# Powershell function return Array not Hashtable

Tags: powershell

I have a problem that I do not understand. I am having a function that looks:

```
Function hashTable
{
    Param($release)

    $releaseArray = @()
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($release))
    {
        $releaseArray = $release.split("{|}", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        $releaseArray.gettype() | Select-Object Name
        if($releaseArray.Count -gt 0) {
            $namePathArray = @{}
            foreach($namePath in $releaseArray) {
                $splitReleaseArray = $namePath.split("{,}", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
                $namePathArray.add($splitReleaseArray[0], $splitReleaseArray[1])
            }

            #here it echos propper hashtable

            $namePathArray.gettype() | Select-Object Name
            if($namePathArray.Count -gt 0) {
                #here it echos propper hashtable as well
                return $namePathArray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I call this function im getting an array not a hashtable that looks like:

```
Name
----
String[]
test
reorder
```

example input param: `-release "reorder,c:\Repo\App|test,test"`

And I am wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: What `$releaseArray.gettype() | Select-Object Name` and `$namePathArray.gettype() | Select-Object Name` in your code supposed to do?

Comment: This is somethi ng for earlier debbuging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You effectively pollute the output stream with the `GetType() |Select Name` statements. Remove them, or use `Write-Host` to display the type names instead:

```
Function hashTable
{
    Param($release)

    $releaseArray = @()
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($release))
    {
        $releaseArray = $release.split("{|}", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Write-Host ($releaseArray.gettype() | Select-Object -Expand Name)
        if($releaseArray.Count -gt 0) {
            $namePathArray = @{}
            foreach($namePath in $releaseArray) {
                $splitReleaseArray = $namePath.split("{,}", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
                $namePathArray.add($splitReleaseArray[0], $splitReleaseArray[1])
            }

            #here it echos propper hashtable

            Write-Host ($namePathArray.gettype() | Select-Object -Expand Name)
            if($namePathArray.Count -gt 0) {
                #here it echos propper hashtable as well
                return $namePathArray
            }
        }
    }
}
```